# Add a Favicon to AWS/S3 - Ember.js

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, ember.js, amazon-s3, favicon

I've uploaded the favicon in my **bucket root** for S3. I've linked the favicon in the html file of the project:

```
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
```

Where `images` is a public folder.

The problem is when I locally host the web app it displays the Favicon,

but it only displays the Favicon on Production when I inspect the source of the page. Or when I reload the page beyond login.
I don't know if this is a bug that I should report, or if I'm doing something wrong.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Locally host means what you do?

Comment: @error2007s , I mean you run `ember s` in the terminal and it runs locally on your machine. EX. `http://localhost:xxx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say route bucket do you mean root on bucket? The image should be placed in the bucket root and make sure that bucket has a public access for this file (right click and make it public inside aws console). So try to place icon inside root of the S3 bucket and make it public. Then reference it like this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/icon.png">
```

if you use png or just ico in your case - but it should in root and public. 
Hope it helps

Comment: Awesome :D Worked like a charm !